Cucumber and Springboot tests to mvn test
Im triying to set my cucumber test in mvn test, but I cant.
You can check the repository in https://github.com/marcotenorioNTT/automation-api-framework
I did use this plugin:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>

But it only works with JUnit test, not with cucumber and features. I tried too with:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/Cucumber*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Bur it doesnt work neither.
I would appreciate your help!
Im expecting to set my cucumber test with the maven test in order to make a prehook that checks the test.
--- Edit:
I tried to set JUnit 5 but now cucumber doesnt find my features.
I tried using cucumber-junit-platform engine but this is not finding my features.
This is my cucumber runner right now:
package org.example;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.example.api.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;
@CucumberContextConfiguration

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)


@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "org.example.steps.specific")

public class CucumberRunner {}

pom.xml
I tried to set src/test/resources/features instead of features.

@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectPackages("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME,
value = "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.html")
Try to use following annotation in order to make it run.

You are using cucumber-junit which uses JUnit 4. With latest version of Spring Boot, the JUnit Platform is used. This only supports JUnit 5.
You can either use the JUnit Vintage Engine from JUnit 5 to run JUnit 4 tests with JUnit 5. Or you can use the cucumber-junit-platform-engine. The cucumber-java-skeleton shows how.

Hi! Thank you!, I am triying to set cucumber-junit-platform-engine but now cucumber is not finding the features. I did a edit on the post just in case you would like to check it.

Can't say based of what you posted. Do make sure to update Surefire. If the skeleton project works for you then it would help to carefully look for differences.
